# How to pass a Type of UIViewController to a function and type cast a variable in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, casting

**Explanation**

I am defining a generic API method to handle popup across my application. Is it possible to pass a type of a UIViewController to a function and type cast the variable popOverVC in the function to the type of popUpVC ie., passed to the function as argument. All programs under Swift are appreciable

**Reference Code**

```
func showAsPopUp(currentVC: UIViewController,currentVCname: String, popupStoryboardID: String, popUpVC:UIViewController){
        let popUpVCType:AnyClass = type(of: popUpVC)
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: currentVCname, bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController(popupStoryboardID) as! popUpVCType
        currentVC.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    }
```

Comment: your `popupStoryboardID` and popUpVCType both are assigned in the same name or else, Generics is the good approach for your concept

Comment: @Anbu.karthik popupStoryboarID is a string which is the storyboardid in UI and popUpVCType is a way to get the type of the PopUpViewController object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good situation to use [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html).

```
func showAsPopUp<T: UIViewController>(currentVC: UIViewController,currentVCname: String, popupStoryboardID: String, popUpVC: T.type) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: currentVCname, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: popupStoryboardID) as! T
    currentVC.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
}
```

Not sure what your functionality is here, but this is how the generics would fit in with the above mentioned code.

The usage of the above method would look like:

```
showAsPopUp(currentVC: UIViewController(), currentVCname: "asdsadv", popupStoryboardID: "asd", popUpVC: SomePopUpViewController.self)
```

Comment: if I pass "PopUpViewController" class as parameter will it convert the Generic Template T as PopUpViewController instead of UIViewController? PopUpViewController is a child of UIVIewController

Comment: @ThomasEaso Sure! You will need to write the code as in the latest edit above.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution was really useful